# netty-socketio xhr-polling regression?

Tags: java, javascript, android, xmlhttprequest, socket.io

Last week i decided to upgrade my version of mrniko netty-socketio from version the old version 1.0.0 to the newest 1.5.2, i upgraded old dependencies too.

But now xhr-polling doesn't work, and if i run my old project using 1.0.0 version everything is working fine !

(i use the 9.1.16 socket.io.client)

The process is :

On the client (javascript) :

```
mServer.on('connect', function() {
    mServer.emit("CON", "HELLO");               
};
```

Here my server receive the event, but when i respond to the client (version 1.5.2) :

```
mSocketIOClient.sendEvent("EVENT", "TEXTDATA");
```

The client receive nothing !

I have try with different browser on desktop and android, and this problem only appears when i use the version 1.5.2 of mrniko socketio.

I have force using xhr-polling with the parameters on client side :

```
transports: ['xhr-polling']});
```

Thanks !

EDIT : Now i tried every version from 1.0.0 to 1.5.3-SNAPSHOT and no one is functionnal with xhr-polling.

The only version where the client receive an event through XHR-polling is the 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

The mysterious thing is that the server receive the data emitted by the client throught javascript emit function, but when the server respond with sendEvent() the client doesn't receive an empty message 3::

I continue my investigation !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed it. Could you please test it on current 1.5.5-SNAPSHOT verison?

**UPDATED**: fixed in 1.6.0 version

Comment: Hi mrniko ! I see that you have seen my post and you made a big update on xhr-polling today too ! But i can't download the 1.5.5-SNAPSHOT from maven what's wrong !?

Comment: Finally i download the git hub project locally, after different test it seems that it's working again !! A big thanks Nikita !

Comment: Not at all. Feel free to post a future bugs as issue on github. Thanks for using!